# How to make simple but effective Hitbox with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on my first game, Catch the cat. I'm new to pygame so don't expect a lot from me.

It is simple game, where you need to click on a cat. As the score goes higher, the cat will go faster.

I need to make hitbox for the cat. Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
    #IMPORTS FOR THE GAME
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
#game speed settings
FPS = 5
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Display settings
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Catch the cat')
#background music settings
pygame.mixer.music.load('backmusic.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
#COLORS
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
AQUA = (0, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
HITBOXCOLOR = (0, 255, 255, 255)
#CAT IMAGE SETUP
catImg = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
catx = 10
caty = 20
direction = 'right'
# SCORE DISPLAY SETUP
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
score = 0
textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(str(score), True, AQUA, BLACK)
textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
textRectObj.center = (10, 10)
while True:
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
    DISPLAY.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)
    if direction == 'right':
        catx += 5
        if catx == 300:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        caty += 5
        if caty == 300:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        catx -= 5
        if catx == 10:
            direction = 'up'
    elif direction == 'up':
        caty -= 5
        if caty == 20:
            direction = 'right'
    DISPLAY.blit(catImg, (catx, caty))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: The simplest one is to make `rect` around the cat(using picture dimensions) and then use `rect.collidepoint()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects. You can get a rectangle with the size of the cat by [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) from the cat surface. Set the position of the cat by the key word attribute `topleft`.
Use the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event and `collidepoint()` to test if the mouse is on the cat when it is clicked:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cat_rect = catImg.get_rect(topleft = (catx, caty))
            if cat_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print("hit")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have helped me a lot with this.